# LINQ Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Tags: linq

I have something like the following:

```
    var lst = db.usp_GetLst(ID,Name, Type);

    if (lst.Count == 0)
    {

    }
```

I get a swigly lie under lst.Count == 0 and it says:

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Answer (score 82, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) is an extension method, not a property. This means `usp_GetLst` probably returns `IEnumerable<T>` (or some equivalent) rather than a derivative of `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` which you expected.

```
// Notice we use lst.Count() instead of lst.Count
if (lst.Count() == 0)
{

}

// However lst.Count() may walk the entire enumeration, depending on its
// implementation. Instead favor Any() when testing for the presence
// or absence of members in some enumeration.
if (!lst.Any())
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes addition of model on top of view is missing that time you will get same error
eg. - @model List<Test.Admin.Models>