# Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'Method Group' and 'int'

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to get the number of elements in this string array, but it won't let me take 1 away from `Count`.

```
string [] Quantitys = Program.RecieptList[i].ItemQuantitys.Split(new char[] {'*'});
for (int ii = 0; i <= Quantitys.Count - 1; ii++)
{

}
```

I get an error message stating

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Method Group' and 'Int'.

Whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: did you mean to use both `ii` and `i` in your loop? It will loop forever unless you handle `i` in your loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199680/linq-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-method-group-and-int)

Answer (score 18):

It should be `Length` not `Count` for arrays:

```
string [] Quantitys = Program.RecieptList[i].ItemQuantitys.Split(new char[] {'*'});
for (int ii = 0; i <= Quantitys.Length - 1; ii++)
{

}
```

More information on the MSDN: [Array.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx)

Also, unless it was intentional, your `ii` should just be `i` in your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Quantitys.Length - 1; i++)
```

Although, as was pointed out in the comments below, you could also use the  `Quantitys.Count()`, since arrays inherit from `IEnumerable<T>`. Personally, though, for one-dimensional arrays, I prefer to use the standard `Array.Length` property.

Comment: @Nathan:  If you're used to working with lists, the IEnumerable methods are available to you with arrays.  In fact, the error you got was because you forgot parentheses for the Linq `Count()` method.

Comment: @AustinSalonen, since `IList<>` implements `IEnumerable<>`, you could technically do the same thing with lists too.

Comment: But `Array` implements `ICollection`, which defines `Count` (property). You can use it with an explicit `ICollection` cast (it will still return `Lenght`). But why do I need to cast?

Comment: Is it because of explicit `ICollection.Count` interface implementation ?https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e0bf122d0e52a42688b92bb4be2cfd66ca3c2f07/mscorlib/system/array.cs#L680

Comment: Yes, `System.Array` effectively hides the `ICollection.Count`, so unless you cast it as `IList` (which I advise against) or `ICollection`, you're not hitting it directly. You could technically use it that way, but I typically steer away from using `ICollection` directly outside of the occasional extension method. Need to iterate/enumerate? Use `IEnumerable`. Key value pair? `IDictionary`. etc, etc.

Answer (score 18):

Simply add brackets (). Count() works for me now as well

Comment: This was already mentioned in the comments of the first answer.

Comment: @JSTL "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. "

Answer (score 5):

Arrays have a `Length` property, not a `Count` property, though they do the same thing. The error you're seeing is because there's an extension method `Count()` that it's finding instead, but can't quite use because you didn't invoke it with `()`. You could use your array as an `IList<T>` instead so that you can keep the familiar `Count` property name.

Also, `i` and `ii` will be confusing to most people (including yourself, from the looks of it: you included both in your `for` line). The standard in programming, carried over from mathematics, is `i`, `j`, `k`, ... for index variable names. This will work:

```
IList<string> Quantitys = Program.RecieptList[i].ItemQuantitys.Split(new char[] {'*'});
for (int j = 0; j <= Quantitys.Count - 1; j++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I added List then its working

before :

```
@model warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS
```

after

```
@model List<warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS>`
```

then the for loop :

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
            </tr>
        }
```