# Why is an Array.Count not allowed as its own index value?

Tags: c#, sorting, generic-list, arrays, indexer

I need to sort a value alphabetically (invoice_no/invoiceNum). I have the following code to do that:

```
string beginningInvoiceNum = string.Empty;
string endingInvoiceNum = string.Empty;
. . .
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stringifiedXML);
var DeliveredItems = doc.Descendants("DSD").Select(delItem => new
{
    lineID = delItem.Element("line_id").Value,
    invoiceNum = delItem.Element("invoice_no").Value,
    UPCCode = delItem.Element("upc_code").Value,
    desc = delItem.Element("description").Value,
. . .
}).ToList(); 

string[] invNums = new string[DeliveredItems.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (var delItem in DeliveredItems)
{
    invNums[i] = delItem.invoiceNum;
    i++;
}
Array.Sort(invNums);
beginningInvoiceNum = invNums[0];
//endingInvoiceNum = invNums[invNums.Count - 1]; <= this does not work
endingInvoiceNum = invNums[DeliveredItems.Count-1]; // <= this works
```

...but as you can see in the comments, my initial attempt to use the string array's count failed; I was scolded with to-me-confusing err msg "*Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'*"

What?!? Isn't invNums.Count the same thing as DeliveredItems.Count? Why does the latter work while the former fails?

### UPDATE

So my code is now this:

```
beginningInvoiceNum = invNums.First();
endingInvoiceNum = invNums.Last();
```

...and I'm happy as an unbaked clam about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'Method Group' and 'int'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526702/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-method-group-and-int)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`invNums` is array, it does not have `Count` property (like list). You should use its [Array.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
invNums[invNums.Length - 1]
```

Or [Enumerable.Count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension of IEnumerable (actually compiler thinks you are trying to use this extension, but instead of executing method you are trying to use method group):

```
invNums[invNums.Count() - 1]
```

Actually in latter case you can use [`Enumerable.Last()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension:

```
invNums.Last()
```

Comment: And that gave me the clue I could use invNums.First(), too; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error message was caused by the fact that `Array.Count` references the `Count` extension method as though it were a property, i.e. without the parentheses. The term "method group" is the clue in the error message.

As Sergey writes, use `invNums.Length - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Because *DeliveredItems* is **list<>**

so it can get count by

```
DeliveredItems.Count
```

but *invNums* is **string array**

therefore we get count of array via

```
invNums.Count()
```

but not 
`invNums.Count` because the latter is only method.

As conclusion, invNums.Count (method) is not the same thing as DeliveredItems.Count (int).